# Why is a duplicate key error being thrown and value still inserted

Tags: c#, mongodb, uuid

A document is inserted into a collection using c#

```
{
   "_id" : UUID("some_guid")
}
```

Via

```
db.collection.insert(new { id = a_guid });
```

We rely upon the uniqueness of the guid/uuid by specifying the id in the document meaning the mongo db driver is spared from doing this.

Now, all of this is wrapped in a try..catch where a duplicate key exception is caught.   Calling code uses this routine for conflict checking. That is, if  a guid hasnt been encountered before - insert it - next time around and on trying to insert the same value again, the exception lets us now there's a duplicate.

We appear to be getting into a situation where values are written but an exception is STILL thrown, indicating a conflict where there isnt one.

We have had this working in a 3 node replica set.

It is NOT working in a 5 node replica set, purporting to be healthy.  The write concern is set to 1, indicating acknowledgement when the master is written to (but not the journal) just like the 3 node set.

Where should I dig deeper? The duplicate exception derives from a writeconcern exception, is something screwy going on here? Is the mongo driver correctly interpreting the error and raising the right exception?

Any leads would be great!

EDIT:

```
        var database = this.client.GetServer().GetDatabase("A_Database");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<object>("A_Collection");

        try
        {
            collection.Insert(new { Id = paymentReference.ToGuid() });
        }
        catch (MongoDuplicateKeyException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
```

This is NOT called in a loop.

Comment: Mongo 2.6.x. The c# driver is the latest one I believe.

Comment: Why don't you show us the so-called exception messages, type, possible inner exception..

Comment: Erm, i thought a highlevel description would be enough to rouse someones knowledge or experiences. MongoDuplicateKeyException.   The exception is swallowed and false (indicating duplicate) is returned via insert method.  The reason may be buried in a log. Even knowing how to retrieve this would be helpful...

Comment: Besides, simply wrap a try catch, in your minds eye ,around the insert I have detailed and thats mostly the sum of the code...

Comment: No Code, no answer. You are clearly doing something in your actual code, but that is missing from this question. It is also not possible for a "single operation" to cause a "duplicate key error" and also write to the database, and therefore you must have multiple write operations that you are mistaking for a single one. At any rate, less of the comments and musing in the question as well and **more** direct example of code that actually produces the errors in your problem. Write it like you are asking the person sitting next to you.

Comment: @Blakes -  Unfortunately I am not doing anything in my code that I think you might be anticipating.  I explained everything of note in the question (s)  I agree though that the insert should be atomic, and potentially this code just might be being called more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately the short code listing there does not match your description *"... if a guid hasnt been encountered before - insert it - next time around and on trying to insert the same value again.."* so clearly you are doing that but the short listing here does not attempt to reproduce this. If you want say *"sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't"* then there needs to be a reproducible case that proves this. So again, this essentially comes down to your real and complete code implementation, which of course is not being shown here.

Comment: @Blakes You must be misinterpreting what I have written! And the code listing does not attempt to show passing in a GUID, why would I have to?!.  I think you are taking my description too literally. I describe what happens and not the code explicitly, the code is v.straightforward.  And so, you must agree that if a GUID has not been encountered - it is inserted. If the same GUID is passed again an exception is raised.  What are you struggling with here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hear's a fixed version of your code

```
    var database = this.client.GetServer().GetDatabase("A_Database");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<object>("A_Collection");

    try
    {
        collection.Insert(new { Id = paymentReference.ToGuid() });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        collection.Insert(new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); });
        return tru;
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, however, I think that you, like '@Blakes'  - who seems a bit unhinged if you ask me - , are having trouble understanding what it is I am actually saying.   Also, you have changed the behaviour of the routine as you return tru (sic).   Was this intentional?

Comment: Actually mate that has completely solved my problem.  I'm such an idiot.  I don't know what I was doing.  No Code No Answer is my new motto :)  You are the best.

Comment: Cheers m8, when u upgrade 2 .net 6 u get the tru keyword.

Comment: .Net 6,  I didn't even know that was out for 2 years.  God I am so behind.  And one less letter in the boolean values seems even better, I cant imagine how many "e's" that will saving me typing.  I wonder if false is shortened too?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception base `MongoWriteException` and filter with [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) by the Category, example code:

```cs
var database = this.client.GetServer().GetDatabase("A_Database");
var collection = database.GetCollection<object>("A_Collection");

try
{
    collection.Insert(new { Id = paymentReference.ToGuid() });
}
catch (MongoWriteException ex) when(ex.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
```